# Paperclip usage with form_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm attempting to get paperclip working with a rails application, and have been unsuccessful so far. Please help me do so; I've included what I think to be the relevant information below, and will be responsive to questions.

It's saving the name of an uploaded photo to the database, and seems to have a path:

```
[13] pry(main)> Order.last
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Order id: 22, quantity: 13, created_at: "2013-02-03 21:47:46", updated_at: "2013-02-03 21:47:46", user_id: 8, drawing_file_name: "friends.jpg", drawing_content_type: nil, drawing_file_size: nil, drawing_updated_at: nil>
[14] pry(main)> Order.last.drawing
  Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> /system/orders/drawings/000/000/022/original/friends.jpg
```

However:

- I can't find anything under that path, on my system or within the application files
- From other answers like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221076/paperclip-not-saving-no-errors), it seems like my params hash passed from the form should have a lot more content; right now, it's only a string name, which seems too short

  ```
  [2] pry(#<OrdersController>)> params
   => {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eTInEukPQ84uIw3TPIdI+u0zo49dQlY68gxrodIoPdA=", "quantity_field"=>"34", "drawing_field"=>["friends.jpg"], "supplier_list"=>["1", "2"], "commit"=>"Create order", "multipart"=>"true", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"orders"}
  ```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quantity, :drawing
  has_attached_file :drawing,
                                    :url => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                                    :path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'create', :controller => 'orders', :multipart => true do %>

....

<div>
  <%= file_field :order, :drawing %>
  <%= label_tag :drawing, 'Attach drawing here' %>
</div>

<%= submit_tag "Create order", :disable_with => "Creating..." %>
```

orders_controller.rb

```
def create

#binding.pry

@order = Order.new#(params[:order])
@order.quantity = params[:quantity_field]
@order.user_id = current_user.id
@order.drawing = params[:order][:drawing]
did_order_save = @order.save

....
```

When I try to make a new order, I get:

```
    Started POST "/orders?multipart=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-05 20:07:20 -0800
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eTInEukPQ84uIw3TPIdI+u0zo49dQlY68gxrodIoPdA=", "quantity_field"=>"334", "order"=>{"drawing"=>"profileBox.png"}, "supplier_list"=>["1"], "commit"=>"Create order", "multipart"=>"true"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'kGRbFvLaYseFaHvRR6sy6w' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19882ms

Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "profileBox.png"):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:54:in `create'
```

I have paperclip/imagemagick installed, have done the migration and confirmed that drawing_file_name etc. are in the database, and have restarted server since.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `<%= file_field :order, :drawing %>`?

Comment: @Wukerplank - Thanks for responding! I've changed it to use file_field, but still have a similar error. Any other ideas?

Comment: It seems as if your form is not submitted as multipart; this seems odd: `Started POST "/orders?multipart=true"` and also in your params: `"order"=>{"drawing"=>"profileBox.png"}` this should not be happening as it means that there is no file, but only a string with the file name. It might be a tiny error, but it's hard to tell from here.

Comment: I've refactored the form_tag and it's now multiparting successfully; will post solution when I get there, but I'm at least over the first roadblock. Thanks for pointing this out, it was the right direction.